# How to manipulate save name of the images

Tags: python, image, opencv, save

I am saving my video frames with below code but I want to add save_path to file name as well:

```
cv2.imwrite(f"{save_path}/{idx}.png", frame)
```

How could I add save_path to file name?

I need it as:

save_path/idxsavepath

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty?  `f"{save_path}/{idx}{save_path}.png"`

Comment: The difficulty is to add filename both idx and  folder name. I have already tried it but it didn't work. if folder name is frames I want it as idxframes.png.

Comment: Then show us what you tried, and what happened as a result, and explain why it wasn't what you wanted.  Telling us "it didn't work" is meaningless.

Comment: if idx % gap == 0:
                cv2.imwrite(f"{save_path}/{idx}{save_path}.png", frame) is what I have tried. But it didn't extract any frames. Before adding {savepath} it was working.

Comment: Does `save_path` contain slashes?

Comment: the folder is empty. It didn't extractframes so there is no filename.

Comment: save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, name)
    create_dir(save_path)

Comment: You'd have to show us the actual value of `f"{save_path}/{idx}{save_path}.png"`.

Comment: and name = video_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]

Comment: sorry didn't understand what you asked for.

Comment: Before calling `imwrite()` on that filename, print it.  And then show us what it printed.

Comment: D:/save\frames_vieo\4

Comment: That filename doesn't end in `.png`, but aside from that, it seems ok.  Does the folder `D:/save\frames_vieo` exist?

Comment: yes but it is as "D:\save\frames_vieo". But it prints "D:/save\frames_vieo\4" I didn't understand why.

Comment: maybe you wanna learn about the meaning of **backslashes in strings**. they escape special characters. you might wanna stick to only forward slashes, or learn about python's r-strings. you should also review [ask] and [mre]. half the information for this question is scattered in a back-and-forth in the comments. such a question will be useless to everyone, including yourself.

Comment: I still couldn't solve the / issue. I am gonna ask it on seperate question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since we lack the debugging info, here is a piece of code you should have written to avoid path problems. first, check that the directory is found and only then continue.

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np


def main():
    # before continuing, must check if folder exists
    save_dir = r'D:\pics'
    valid_path = os.path.exists(save_dir)
    print('is {} a valid path ? {}'.format(save_dir, valid_path))

    if not valid_path:
        print('folder {} does not exist - create it and try again'.format(save_dir))
    else:
        idx = 0
        fake_frame = np.zeros(shape=(480, 640, 3))
        image_full_path = '{}/{}.png'.format(save_dir, idx)
        cv2.imwrite(image_full_path, fake_frame)
        print('image saved successfully on {}'.format(image_full_path))
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```